# F11 not presenting code of Macaulay 2 to the Emacs buffer in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, emacs

I am setting up Emac Version 24.4 (9.0) for [Macaulay 2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2). This results to the following error: pressing F11 should present the input of the buffer above, instead it prints `"-- end of buffer *M2-demo-buffer*"`. I don't know:

**How can I get the emacs to present the code in the above buffer as in the picture?**

Related the last question, in other words with different buffer, how can I get the code highlighted with mouse to be presented to Macaulay 2 buffer in Emacs with F11?

[image]

The F keys are not mapped in dashboard or expose.

[image]

*This point is missing in [instructions](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/MacOSX/ReadMe-MacOSX.txt) to set up M2 for emacs in OSX.*

Comment: Which function is F11 bound to?

Comment: @patrix F11 makes the selected window wide but only in Emacs (not in every window, I cannot yet understand which controls this thing): the green ball on the left corner of each window in OSX -- is this some setting possible to adjust in OSX?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way, thanks to Marc for demonstrating M2 and Emacs.

> The file you are modifying in the above buffer needs to have ending `*.m2`
>
> [image]
>
> where notice the heading at the top and the highlighted code for showing that the code is getting read correctly.

by this way, Emacs determines which compiler it uses for the selected code. So

1. Save as File.m2
2. `F12` opens up the M2 promth
3. `F11` interepts a single line at a time

Wuoala, M2 works out of the box with Emacs, awesome.

Enjoy.